# Is it possible to generate a paypal express button without form?

Tags: paypal

I have created a command to get a markup from Paypal API and it returns me a form with Paypal button and some hidden input fields. Is it possible to generate a Paypal express button without a form and contains URL including the item details?

Comment: Huh? _it returns me a **form** with Paypal button and some hidden input fields_ ?

Comment: Please clarify the question. You seem to be mixing terms from different PayPal products.

Comment: Is using a form the ONLY way that paypal will generate a paypal express button?